# UITableView Row Select glitch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an iOS app where users can select their favorite attractions. I want to show this with a checkmark in a `UITableView`. When debugging, I found that when users select (for example) 4 attractions and scroll down, other attractions will have a checkmark as well. Even when the users hasn't selected them. Is this a common bug/glitch?

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = items[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *tableCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL isSelected = (tableCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark);

    if (isSelected) {
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else {
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

}
```

`

Here's a [.gif file](https://i.gyazo.com/d62bf9eb06dfaf4f42b71b7904b291df.gif) to show you what is happening at rumtime:

Comment: You have to keep track of which rows have been selected, and then apply that in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Cells are reused. Keep a track of cells which have been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *selectedIndexPaths;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   ...

    _selectedIndexPaths = [NSMutableSet set];

   ...
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...

    tableCell.accessoryType = ([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
        ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
        : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    ...
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...

    UITableView *tableCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Avi! It works perfectly!

Comment: Don't just post code as an answer. Provide some explanation of what was wrong and what your answer fixes.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very common bug but not an iOS one.  :)

The problem is that cells get reused and, if you change an aspect of the cell, it is not automatically reset to any default when it's given to you again.

The strategy to use is: save the "selected" state in the data you use to populate your cells and then turn the accessory on or off in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug/glitch. It's what it should be. Because you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. You have to reset the state of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

For selected cells, you should create an array to handle the index of selected.

Comment: Semantically, an `NSMutableSet` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should save a list of the selected rows in an `array` and check `isSelected` should check if the `array` has that row.